# How to clone a linux live server with no stopping it?

Tags: linux, backup, replication

This is my current situation:+
A linux server containing several web applications that cannot be stopped, with no physical access to it, only via ssh.

This is what I need:
I need to replicate it to a virtual machine on my computer in order to make some operations that might be risky.

What I tried:
I tried `dump` command running this line on live server:

```
dump -0aLf / | ssh user@backup-server dd of=/path/to/destination/data.dump
```

But it fails to open devices in `/dev/` showing this message:

```
DUMP: Date of this level 0 dump: Mon Sep  1 16:52:14 2014
DUMP: Dumping /dev/vzfs (/) to /dev/tape
DUMP: Cannot open /dev/vzfs
DUMP: The ENTIRE dump is aborted.
```

My questions:

- Shall I exclude /dev/ tree from Dump command? how this should be done?
- Should I run another command to make this replica?

Comment: I'd say have you should aim to replicate the applications, not their state. Also, you probably know the whole stack being used, so it should be easier to deploy the same applications on a fresh VM.

Comment: The aim is testing in advance how the live server would work with new configuration and applications

Comment: You can only `dump` actual filesystems, not the fake filesystems that OpenVZ presents to VEs.

Comment: Is this a physical machine, or is it already virtualised?  If the latter, what's the virtualisation technology?

Comment: Looks like you server is virtualized with OpenVZ or equivalent. Every virtualisation technique has a cloning method - ask the sysadmin of the VM to make you a clone.

If that is not an option and you have to do it from inside your VM: many low-level backup tools have an option to restrict the operation to a single filesystem and to exclude dirs. "tar" can to a pretty good job, look at its options "--one-file-system" and "--exclude". That will help you to exclude /dev /proc /sys and so on

Comment: Also note that OpenVZ containers are often incomplete, e.g. they might not contain a kernel. Don't expect a copy to run out-of-the-box on a physical machine or as a VM on some other virtualisation technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can always just do a tar.gz. I have done this to clone systems. Obviously, you need to create partitions, format, and mount before untar on the destination system. Also, you will need to install grub after, and of course root privileges on the source machine.

I usually list each partition separately and use `--one-file-system`. For example, imagine you have a system with `/`, `/boot`, `/usr`, `/var` and `/tmp` different partitions. You could do a tarball of the whole system like this:

```
tar --one-file-system -cjpf backup.tar.bz2 / /boot /usr /var"
```

Also `/sys`, `/dev`, `/proc`, `/tmp` would need to be created in the destination system. `/dev` could be included in the tarball, it doesn't harm. Here you are copying also `/var/tmp` just because it is not a separate partition from `/var`, you could always use `--exclude` if you don't want to copy it. Usually I don't care if it's not too big.

Other than that, that would copy a running system which can contain certain inconsistencies (for example running databases). The effect when starting the copy for the first time will be as if the machine had been powered off abruptly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you are going to clone a Linux server without administrative privileges (read: root).

It seems you're trying to ensure a change is first tested in a separate environment (which doesn't currently exist). The question is, what layers is this change going to touch?

If you know which components are going to be updated/changed, you know what to focus on. Let's say this is a CentOS 6 server running MySQL 5.1 and the change is to upgrade to MySQL 5.5 (whatever). Build a separate CentOS 6 machine, install MySQL 5.1, replicate the data and configuration, then attempt the upgrade and test.

If this machine cannot be stopped, how are you patching it? I hope you're. If so, it can be stopped and just need some arranges. Your best option is to stop it and consider doing a p2v operation so you've an exact system running in a virtual machine somewhere to experiment with (and much easier to break and restore many times, if needed).